# I am getting error (BC30451) when I try compile my project. What is this error?

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an error (BC30451), with my code, but I just can't seem to work out what it is. I've been working on this for a while now, and it's really annoying how I can't compile it.

Code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class Login1

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.Google.com") Then

            MsgBox("Your Computer is currently connected to our database.", "Success!")
        Else

            MsgBox("Your Computer is currently not connected to our servers.", "Fatal Error")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox8.Text = My.Settings.username AndAlso TextBox9.Text = My.Settings.password Then
            MsgBox("You have successfully been logged in!")
            Close()
            Main.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("That username or password is incorrect, please try again.")
            Me.Close()
            Form1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the `Main.Show()`, it's saying that `Main` is not declared, even though it's a valid project within Visual Studio I'm using.

Also, for some reason, next to 'Main.vb', instead of the normal software box you should get, it just has a blue logo saying 'VB'. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's a class not a form and so `Main.Show()` won't work. Look at `Login1.vb`. That's a form.

Comment: I get it now, thank you!